# Methods/approach to simplify $k^2(k+1)^2 + 4(k+1)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi guys are there any other Methods/approach to simplify $k^2(k+1)^2 + 4(k+1)^3$ instead of expanding everything out and getting a quartic and cubic?? I expanded the entire thing out and got a quartic and cubic which both i have used factor theorem and long division. In the end i have got $(k+1)^2 \cdot (k+2)^2$ which is the answer, but this approach took too long to solve. So my question is are there any more simpler approach so can i do this quicker?

Comment: I have tried to edit your math. But after reading your answer I suspect you meant $+$ and not $\cdot$ (a . usually means multiplication, so that's what I assumed). If that's the case, could you please edit all the relevant `\cdot` in your question into `+`?

Comment: You can take the $(k+1)$ as a factor ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really mean $k^2(k+1)^2\cdot 4(k+1)^3=4k^2(k+1)^5$ which should not be simplyfied further, because it does not get simpler then that.

It always depends on what you want to do with your term.

If you mean $k^2(k+1)^2+4(k+1)^3$ you can factor out $(k+1)^2$ and get:

$(k+1)^2(k^2+4k+4)=(k+1)^2(k+2)^2$

Where we used the binomial formula, to see $k^2+4k+4=(k+2)^2$

Comment: how did u get k^2+4k+4??? @cornman sorry i do not understand

Comment: After you factor out $(k+1)^2$ you are left with: $(k+1)^2(k^2+4(k+1))=(k+1)^2(k^2+4k+4)$